# Why am I getting a FileNotFoundException when the file is there?

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamreader, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to save a file to the server and then load into a reader for it to be downloaded. However, I am getting a *FileNotFoundExeption*. I save to the exact same path, manually open the directory and can see the file there. However, reading it results in the exception. This is my first time trying his - am I doing something wrong?

```
try 
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new 
           StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Downloads/data.text"))) 
    {
       // do something
    }
}
catch (Exception) 
{

}
```

Comment: Did you check the permissions?

Comment: Have you confirmed that `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Downloads/data.text")` resolves correctly to the path you need?

Comment: Is that supposed to be data.txt?

Comment: Is your app pool configured to run under a security account that doesn't have access to this subfolder by any chance?

Comment: Did you already check out this SO question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146652/streamreader-complains-that-file-does-not-exist-but-it-does

Comment: @Oded If it's an error with the permission, the system will output "Access Denied" but not a `FileNotFoundException`. I believe that there's a problem with resolving `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Downloads/data.text")`. Have a great day :)

Comment: @Yatrix May you please show us the actual file path `data.text`?

Comment: @FantaMango77 I just checked it out. I also did a GetFiles and it displayed the file being there.

Comment: @PicrofoEGY \\kit-storage\users\myname\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\GridViewTest\Downloads\data.txt

Comment: @evanmcdonnal That's what I saved it as, yes. Why?

Comment: @Oded I would think I'd get an access related error for that. It's telling me the file's not there. Would that be a permission thing?

Comment: Because .text is not a common file extension where as .txt is and FileNotFoundExceptions are usually the result of pathing errors.

Comment: @Oded I have full permissions on the directory, for the record. =)

Comment: @Yatrix I see that the file name is different from the code you posted. Your code represents the file path as follows: `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Downloads/data.text")` while the file is located at `\\kit-storage\users\myname\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\GridViewTest\Downloads\data.txt`. Perhaps removing '~\' and replacing '.text' with '.txt' would solve the problem.

Comment: @PicrofoEGY Dammit to hell!!!

Comment: @Yatrix I'm glad you had this issue resolved. Have a great day :)

Comment: @PicrofoEGY Worked like a charm. On that note, I'm going home. Thanks all. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double-check the file name! In one of your comments you used the file name data.txt and not the name data.text. I suppose it's just a typo in your code.

Comment: ...I should know better than to ask questions after 5 on a damned Friday. It's always going to be something stupid my cashed out brain has overlooked.

Comment: LOL good catch! I dub thee Eagle Eyes!