# Why won't this Path.Combine work?

Tags: c#, io

I have the following command:

```
string reportedContentFolderPath =
Path.Combine(contentFolder.FullName.ToString(), @"\ReportedContent\");
```

When I look in the debugger I can see the following:

```
contentFolder.FullName = "E:\\"
```

However

```
reportedContentFolderPath = "\\ReportedContent\\"
```

Why is the `Path.Combine` chopping off the E:\?

Comment: Try it without the slash on `reportedContentFolderPath`

Comment: CHeck out this previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53102/why-does-path-combine-not-properly-concatenate-filenames-that-start-with-path-dir

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have a leading slash on `@"\ReportedContent\"`. You don't want that (or the trailing one, I suspect) - try just:

```
string reportedContentFolderPath =
    Path.Combine(contentFolder.FullName.ToString(), "ReportedContent");
```

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx):

> If `path2` does not include a root (for example, if `path2` does not start with a separator character or a drive specification), the result is a concatenation of the two paths, with an intervening separator character. If `path2` includes a root, `path2` is returned.

In your case, `path2` *did* contain a root, so it was returned without looking at `path1`.

Answer (score 8):

It is explained in the method documentation:

> If path2 does not include a root (for example, if path2 does not start with a separator character or a drive specification), the result is a concatenation of the two paths, with an intervening separator character. If path2 includes a root, path2 is returned.

I recommend you read it all to understand how all the possible combinations work out: [Path.Combine Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Path.Combine will return the second argument if it begins with a separation character (`\`).

Answer (score 3):

I'd bet that by specifying the slash as prefix in the second string, the Combine method assumes the current drive. Try to remove the slash.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> ```
> public static string Combine(string path1, string path2)
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Return Value
>
> Type: System.String
>   The combined paths. If one of the specified paths is a zero-length string, this method returns the other path. **If `path2` contains an absolute path, this method returns `path2`.**

`@"\ReportedContent\"` is an absolute path because it begins with a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Path.Combine thinks the two slashes `E:\\` refers to a UNC path, and a UNC path should not be prefixed with a drive letter.  Change the contentFolder to `E:\` and it should work.