# c# Path.Combine isn't working right?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to combine a path and a string to create a path, although the path is the string only?
what I mean is, when I use Console.WriteLine(filepath) all that comes out is the string and not the path, and when I write the argument (whats used as the path, its a argument you set when you open the .exe) its comes out properly, as the set path, as the string:

```
string filepath = Path.Combine(arg1, @"\tf1.dat");
```

arg1 is the argument turned into a string.

Comment: Or actually [Why Does Path.Combine not properly concatenate filenames that start with Path.DirectorySeparatorChar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53102/why-does-path-combine-not-properly-concatenate-filenames-that-start-with-path-di), as that one is older.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have the `\` at the start of the second argument. You want:

```
string filepath = Path.Combine(arg1, "tf1.dat");
```

Otherwise it thinks you want an absolute filename, basically.

Comment: Thanks. That '/', So evil!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
string filepath = Path.Combine(arg1, "tf1.dat");
```

Remove the `slash \` from your second argument of `Path.Combine` to avoid making it an absolute filename

Comment: @CodeCaster:- Yes that was simple. But the legend Jon Skeet was as usual quicker to explain the reason!