# Is this a bug on Path.Combine?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to make sure that path always ends with `\` and I try to use Path.Combine as the code below.

I expect `System.IO.Path.Combine("xxx", System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString())` to return `xxx\` but it returns only `\`

The same goes for `System.IO.Path.Combine("xxx", "\\", "zz")` which I expect `xxx\zz` but it turns out to be `\zz`

Here are tests I have done.
[image]

I am not sure if this is a desired behavior or it's a bug.

Comment: `Path.Combine` produces paths. a string ending with a `\\` isn't a valid path.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53102/why-does-path-combine-not-properly-concatenate-filenames-that-start-with-path-di

Comment: @user definitely a duplicate of that one.

Comment: When you want to ask for a bug think twice

Comment: Btw, why do you need "path always ends with \"? To concatenate path with file name? Then, well, this is for what you should use `Path.Combine` (when you use it, you don't care about '\' at the end, you see?).

Comment: The value will be used as a parameter to an external exe file. Unfortunately, that exe file treats `C:\xxxx` as a file while `C:\xxxx\` as a path.

Comment: @Selman22 as I stated on the question, I tested it with a few cases I could come up with. :)

Comment: @Anonymous I understand but you should take a look at the documentation first :)

Answer (score 5):

This is defined behaviour of [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If the second (or any subsequent) path is "rooted", i.e. starts with a path delimiter like '\' or 'c:', any previous parameters are ignored. From the documentation:

> If path2 does not include a root (for example, if path2 does not start
>   with a separator character or a drive specification), the result is a
>   concatenation of the two paths, with an intervening separator
>   character. If path2 includes a root, path2 is returned.

You should not use things like `System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` when using `Path.Combine`, IMHO, it's whole point of being is to make path manipulation easier, not harder.

Answer (score 1):

`Path.Combine` combines paths. If the second parameter is a relative path, the paths are combined; if it is an absolute path, only the second parameter is returned (since combining absolute paths does not make sense). `\` is an absolute path referring to the root directory.

What you want can more easily be achieved by

```
myPath = myPath.TrimEnd('\') + "\";
```

On the other hand, *why* do you need your path to end with a `\`? The whole point of `Path.Combine` is that you don't *need* to have paths ending with `\`. Note the following examples:

```
myPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\xxx", "zz");    // yields C:\xxx\zz
myPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\xxx\", "zz");   // also yields C:\xxx\zz
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for `Combine`:

> If the one of the subsequent paths is an absolute path, then the combine operation resets starting with that absolute path, discarding all previous combined paths.

Since `\` is an absolute path, everything preceding it is discarded.

Answer (score 0):

It's documented behaviour.  From the documentation for [Path.Combine(string path1, string path2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If path2 contains an absolute path, this method returns path2.